# Compare row wise with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a requirement where I have 2 sheets. Now I have to compare the row wise records for each column of the excel. 
For Example:

First Sheet - Sheet1

[image]

Now in second sheet -Sheet2

[image]

Now for each row I need to check that the same row(Concatenated Value of PRODID & PRODCODE with Same value exist in the Sheet2 or not.

I have tried the same with below formula but the problem is it's matching with same row id of both the Sheets.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,"-",B2),CHOOSE({1},CONCATENATE(Sheet2!A2,"-",Sheet2!B2)),1, FALSE)), "No", "Yes")
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS()`

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,B2)>0
```

[image]

Comment: One more thing. My records may have white spaces. So, in countifs how I can remove them?

Comment: You can use TRIM in your equation, for example: `=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM(Sheet2!A2:A5)=TRIM(A2))*(TRIM(Sheet2!B2:B5)=TRIM(B2)))>0`, don't use whole column ranges on this one since it's an array formula.